# What does ‘by’ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ‘by’ mean in the following context. I took the following extract from answer.yahoo.com, on an attempt of defining the meaning of “time-sensitive”. One user defined it as following;

“It means that there is a given amount of time to have it in by.”

But I have trouble to understand the part which is labeled in bold.

Comment: *But I have trouble to understand the part which is labeled in bold.* There is no part in bold.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning becomes clear if the sentence is re-written so that the preposition goes at the beginning of the relative close:

> It means that there is a given amount of time by which to have it in

Answer (score 2):

The preposition *[by](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/by)* in this context means

> not later than:  *be back by ten o'clock*

The original sentence means

> You must have it in by a given amount of time.

The phrase *have [something] in by* is common and often followed by a particular deadline.

> Have it in by 3PM.
>
> Have it in by the end of the week.

Because the definition you read was not setting a particular deadline, but referring to a more general *given amount of time*, using the phrase *by a given amount of time* would sound a bit awkward to most native speakers. *By* would more often be used for a fixed deadline, not a time span. Most native speakers would more likely say

> It means that there is a given amount of time to *get it in*

or

> It must be in *within* a given amount of time [which means *it must be submitted within a given amount of time*]